# Обращение на "ты" и на "вы"

Tags: этикет

В знак уважения к старшему или постороннему мы обращаемся на "вы". "Ты" — признак панибратства. Но почему тогда в молитвах к Богу мы обращаемся на "ты", и, насколько я знаю, о царе тоже говорили иногда так же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обращение "Вы" появилось в русском языке только во времена Петра I. До этого ко всем царям, князьям да и всем остальным обращались на "ты". В ЦСЯ, на котором в православии читают молитвы, равно как и в библейских языках (древнееврейском, арамейском и койне) вежливого местоимения множественного числа для обращения к одному человеку тоже нет. Соответственно все первоначальные молитвы были с обращением "ты", а потом уже согласуясь с традицией оставили без изменений.

В качестве религиозной причины обращения на "ты" приводят довод о том, что Бог для верующего всегда "ближний" и друг, а потому холодное "Вы", при общении с ним и неуместно.

Answer (score 3):

От немцев вполне могло быть, поскольку вежливое Sie употребляется не более двухсот лет, а до того применялось вежливое Ihr, совпадающее как раз с мн.ч 2-го лица. Примеры можно найти даже ещё у Гауфа и Клейста, хотя и сознательно употребленные в качестве архаизма.

Answer (score 1):

К Богу обращаются "на ты", насколько знаю, на всех современных языках.
Не знаю, насколько объективно представление о том, что Бог всегда "ближний друг", мне сдаётся, что все несколько проще. Или сложнее. Тут скорее"Богу-богово, кесарю - кесарево". Не тот менталитет. Ну не нуждается Бог в том, чтобы ему выказывали уважение подобным образом, скорее бы унизило.

Но мне интереснее другое. То, что обращение на "Вы" пошло якобы с Петра, который завез оное от немцев.  Но по-немецки вежливое обращение совсем не совпадает с формой 2-го лица множественного. Оно сопадает (или правильнее сказать - максимально близка) к третьему лицу. Ответ видимо в том, что тогда немцами называли голландцев, язык которых представляет собой нечто промежуточное между немецким и английским, сильно, прада испорченное романским (французским и испанским, что объяснимо для знающих историю, и немного даже итальянским, что вообще никак не объяснимо).
Так вот, в голландском форма везливого обращения в общем-то совпадает с английской, более того, даже пишется с заглавной - U, что объясняет и русское написание.

Answer (score 1):

Обращение на "Вы" уместно по отношению к личности ("совокупности социально значимых черт индивида"), а к душе нужно обращаться на "ты". Поэтому мы и говорим "ты" близким друзьям и врагам.

Бог, как верно заметил Tagirix, находится вне социума и является Сверх-душой. Отсюда Ты. С прописной буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Бог - хотя я в него не верю - является существом, которое не имеет фактически никакого статуса в обществе (он вообще не имеет визуальный вид). Посему я считаю, что к нему можно обращаться и на **ТЫ**.

Comment: С точки зрения православного верующего (я атеист), Бог - это царь царей.

Comment: Бог — близкий человек для смертного человека, так что к нему можно и на«ТЫ».

Comment: В общем-то, на этот взгляд религиозного человека, я и указал во втором абзаце своего ответа.